# Google Apps Script webapp is converting submitted data values to array

Tags: json, ajax, google-apps-script

I have a form on my website that submits its data to a Google App Script which then does some stuff and returns a status back to the web page. For some reason, when it reads in the submitted data, it is converting each value to an array containing just the value. For example:

```
{
  fname: "danny",
  lanme: "tester"
}
```

is being converted to

```
{
  fname[]: ["danny"],
  lanme[]: ["tester"]
}
```

** also not the `[]` being appended to the property name;

**Here's a simple example**:

### HTML

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="fname"> <input type="text" name="lname">
  <submit>
</form>
```

### JavaScript

```
var payload = {
  fname: $('[name="fname"]').val(),
  lname: $('[name="lname"]').val()
}

$('form').submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/SCRIPT_ID/exec',
      data: payload
      method: 'GET"',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data.body));
     }
  });
});
```

### Google Apps Script

```
function doGet(e) {
  var data = e.parameters;
  return ContentService     
   .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data))
   .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT); 
}
```

When run, the following is written to the console:

```
{fname: Array(1), lname: Array(1)}
```

and expanding it produces

```
  fname: ["danny"]
  lanme: ["tester"]
```

It's easy enough to convert in the Google Apps Script, but it would be nice to know why this is happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the way that the `parameters` property works.

You might change your `doGet` function by replacing

```
var data = e.parameters;
```

by

```
var data = {
   fname:e.parameter.fname,
   lname:e.parameter.lname
};
```

or by

```
var data = {};
Object.keys(e.parameter).forEach(key => data[key] = e.parameter[key]);
```

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Gotcha. Yah I'm doing something similar to the 2nd suggestion - just making sure it was completely necessary. Thx!!